# @import susy file installed via npm

Tags: sass, gruntjs, npm

I just installed susy via npm but don't know how to include it in the main scss file. How can I import susy?

I've tried:

```
@import "icons";
@import "nav";
@import "page_home";
@import "../../../susy";
```

where susy is in `/node_modules` and main.scss is in `/app/style/sass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path goes up to the root directory, but doesn't then go down into the `node_modules/susy/` directory.
Try updating `@import` to something like:

```
@import "../../../node_modules/susy/sass/_susy.scss
```

Answer (score 0):

When you import a file you don't need to include the file extension `_` or `.scss`. Sass is smart and will figure it out for you.

```
@import "../../../node_modules/susy/sass/susy";
```